# PHP Slim API returns null after calling get

Tags: mysql, angularjs, api, slim, postman

I run the following code in Postman but all my fields end up as null. I used echo json_encode($cus) to see this. I've been fiddling for hours but I'm not sure where my error is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/Customers', 'getCustomers');
$app->get('/Customers/:id', 'getCustomer');
$app->post('/New_Customer', 'addCustomer');
$app->put('/Customers/:id', 'updateCustomer');
$app->delete('/Customers/:id', 'deleteCustomer');

$app->run();


// Add new Customer to the Database
function addCustomer() {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $cus = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Status) VALUES (:username, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :status)";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("username", $cus->Username);
        $stmt->bindParam("firstname", $cus->First_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam("lastname", $cus->Last_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam("email", $cus->Email);
        $stmt->bindParam("status", $cus->Status);
        $stmt->execute();
        $cus->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($cus); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        //echo json_encode($cus);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
var_dump($cus) results in
object(stdClass)#18 (5) { ["Username"]=> &NULL ["First_Name"]=> &NULL ["Last_Name"]=> &NULL ["Email"]=> &NULL ["Status"]=> &NULL
```

In POSTMAN I am using form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: var_dump($cus) to see actual values you are getting.

Comment: What content-type are you using in POSTMAN....

Comment: var_dump($cus) results in     object(stdClass)#18 (5) { ["Username"]=> &NULL ["First_Name"]=> &NULL ["Last_Name"]=> &NULL ["Email"]=> &NULL ["Status"]=> &NULL

Comment: In POSTMAN I am using form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

(what is your version?)

I look at my slim

your

```
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

mine: version 2.4.2

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing JSON API request must use `Content-Type: application/json` instead of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode`.